# react router dom nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, nested-routes

```
<Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />}>
  <Route path="featured" element={<Featured />} />
  <Route path="previous" element={<Previous />} />
  <Route path="favourites" element={<Favourites />} />
  <Route path=":categoryId/:menuId" element={<MenuDetail />} />
</Route>
```

```
<Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
<Route path="/menu/featured" element={<Featured />} />
<Route path="/menu/previous" element={<Previous />} />
<Route path="/menu/favourites" element={<Favourites />} />
<Route path="/menu/:categoryId/:menuId" element={<MenuDetail />} />
```

I thought these two codes do the same thing but found out they do not. First one being the nested routes under menu route, and the second is just regular routes.
Apparently the second code is what I want it to do.

The first one, when I go to

- `"/menu/featured"`
- `"/menu/previous"`
- `"/menu/favourites"`
- `"/menu/:categoryId/:menuId"`

They all give me `Menu` component, which I do not want. So I had to try the second code to achieve what I wanted.

But aren't they the same?

If I were to achieve what I want using the nested routes, how should I write this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example the `Menu` component is rendered as a layout route. Layout routes components should also render an `Outlet` component for their nested routes to also render out their `element` content. If ***only*** `Menu` is being rendered then I suspect you are missing the `Outlet`.

That said, if you wanted to make the two snippets the same then you'd render `Menu` as an index route of a layout route rendered on `"/menu"`. When a layout `Route` is not passed an `element` prop it renders just an `Outlet` by default.

Example:

```
<Route path="/menu">
  <Route index element={<Menu />} />
  <Route path="featured" element={<Featured />} />
  <Route path="previous" element={<Previous />} />
  <Route path="favourites" element={<Favourites />} />
  <Route path=":categoryId/:menuId" element={<MenuDetail />} />
</Route>
```

Which is equivalent to rendering them all individually unnested with fully qualified route paths.

```
<Route path="/menu" element={<Menu />} />
<Route path="/menu/featured" element={<Featured />} />
<Route path="/menu/previous" element={<Previous />} />
<Route path="/menu/favourites" element={<Favourites />} />
<Route path="/menu/:categoryId/:menuId" element={<MenuDetail />} />
```

Comment: Thank you!! i did not treat the Outlet part as a big deal at first so i excluded them, thinking it was only needed when there are some duplicate codes between parent and child components. Thanks for everything once again!!